How to solve this React native expo build issue in "eas build -p android"?
Run Gradlew
Android Bundled 83681ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (1627 modules)
Writing bundle output to: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle
Writing sourcemap output to: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map
Copying 76 asset files
Done writing bundle output
Done writing sourcemap output
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:763:63: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
...typeof expo === "undefined" ? eval("require") : function (moduleId) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:3362:16: warning: the variable "SharedArrayBuffer" was not declared in function "from"
if (typeof SharedArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && (isInstance(value, Shared...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:7354:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19574:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
setTimeout(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17684:31: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in anonymous function " 375#"
var _nativeFabricUIManage = nativeFabricUIManager,
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17712:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 375#"
cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:22342:30: warning: the variable "REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK" was not declared in anonymous function " 375#"
if ("undefined" !== typeof REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23891:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
setImmediate(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27929:5: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 586#"
fetch,
^~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27930:5: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 586#"
Headers,
^~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27931:5: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 586#"
Request,
^~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27932:5: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 586#"
Response
^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28089:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
var reader = new FileReader();
^~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28140:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 597#"
} else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28142:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 597#"
} else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28144:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 597#"
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28263:26: warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 603#"
var ctrl = new AbortController();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28397:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 607#"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27942:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 589#"
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||
^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:31959:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 764#"
if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...
^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:31982:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 764#"
"undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...
^~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32092:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 764#"
};else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32107:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 764#"
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:43886:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:65790:76: warning: the variable "Buffer" was not declared in function "convertValue"
... 'function' ? new Blob([value]) : Buffer.from(value);
^~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:118347:100: warning: the variable "location" was not declared in function "registerSensor 1#"
...(0, _PlatformChecker.isWeb)() && location.protocol !== 'https:' ? ' Make s...
^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:118998:26: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
workletFun = eval('(' + initData.code + '\n)');
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:119021:112: warning: the variable "_toString" was not declared in function "valueUnpacker"
...recognized by value unpacker: "${_toString(objectToUnpack)}".`);
^~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:119875:11: warning: the variable "queueMicrotask" was not declared in anonymous function " 2981#"
queueMicrotask(function () {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:120001:33: warning: the variable "_WORKLET" was not declared in function "runOnJS"
if (SHOULD_BE_USE_WEB || !_WORKLET) {
^~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:136782:26: warning: the variable "structuredClone" was not declared in function "createAnimationWithExistingTransform"
newAnimationData = structuredClone(_config.AnimationsData[animationName]);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137076:27: warning: the variable "HTMLElement" was not declared in function "findDescendantWithExitingAnimation"
if (!(node instanceof HTMLElement)) {
^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137102:24: warning: the variable "MutationObserver" was not declared in function "addHTMLMutationObserver"
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137151:41: warning: the variable "getComputedStyle" was not declared in function "fixElementPosition"
...entBorderTopValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent).borderTopWidth);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:141507:5: warning: the variable "jest" was not declared in function "beforeTest"
jest.useFakeTimers();
^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:142043:26: warning: the variable "_getAnimationTimestamp" was not declared in function "computeEasingProgress"
var elapsedTime = (_getAnimationTimestamp() - startingTimestamp) / 1000;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:167230:9: warning: the variable "cancelAnimationFrame" was not declared in anonymous function " 5048#"
cancelAnimationFrame(this.renderAheadUpdateCallbackId);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:176800:9: warning: the property "alignItems" was set multiple times in the object definition.
alignItems: "flex-start",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:176794:9: note: The first definition was here.
alignItems: "center",
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:178943:17: warning: the property "width" was set multiple times in the object definition.
width: 30,
^~~~~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:178940:17: note: The first definition was here.
width: "",
^~~~~~~~~
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/i615p4n6/arm64-v8a'
[1/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/ObjectDeallocator.cpp.o
[2/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/LazyObject.cpp.o
[3/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/NativeModule.cpp.o
[4/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/SharedObject.cpp.o
[5/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/JSIUtils.cpp.o
[6/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/TypedArray.cpp.o
[7/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIDeallocator.cpp.o
[8/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/EventEmitter.cpp.o
[9/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIInjector.cpp.o
[10/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/Exceptions.cpp.o
[11/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JNIFunctionBody.cpp.o
[12/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/ExpoModulesHostObject.cpp.o
[13/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/types/FrontendConverterProvider.cpp.o
[14/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaReferencesCache.cpp.o
[15/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSReferencesCache.cpp.o
[16/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptFunction.cpp.o
[17/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JSIContext.cpp.o
[18/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android23 --sysroot=/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Dexpo_modules_core_EXPORTS -I/home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39f4eae6566f15ee45e87b8490d5ccdd/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.3-release/prefab/modules/reactnativejni/include/react -I/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/turbomodule -I/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/../common/cpp -I/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/fabric -isystem /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7f7ab488488f91a0b24570b5fc7cb376/transformed/jetified-fbjni-0.6.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include -isystem /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39f4eae6566f15ee45e87b8490d5ccdd/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.3-release/prefab/modules/jsi/include -isystem /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39f4eae6566f15ee45e87b8490d5ccdd/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.3-release/prefab/modules/reactnativejni/include -isystem /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39f4eae6566f15ee45e87b8490d5ccdd/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.3-release/prefab/modules/folly_runtime/include -isystem /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/39f4eae6566f15ee45e87b8490d5ccdd/transformed/jetified-react-android-0.74.3-release/prefab/modules/react_nativemodule_core/include -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions -frtti -stdlib=libc++ -DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=74 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP=1 -DFOLLY_CFG_NO_COROUTINES=1 -DFOLLY_MOBILE=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_RECVMMSG=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DFOLLY_HAVE_XSI_STRERROR_R=1 -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all -DUSE_HERMES=0 -DUNIT_TEST=0 -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp.o -c /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp
/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:148:28: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'weak_ptr'
auto weakConstructor = std::weak_ptr(constructor);
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4690:51: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp> const& __r,
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4679:28: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS weak_ptr
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4694:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
weak_ptr(weak_ptr const& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4695:51: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(weak_ptr<_Yp> const& __r,
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4701:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
weak_ptr(weak_ptr&& __r) _NOEXCEPT;
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4702:51: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'weak_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
template _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY weak_ptr(weak_ptr<_Yp>&& __r,
^
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4689:23: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR weak_ptr() _NOEXCEPT;
^
1 error generated.
[19/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptRuntime.cpp.o
[20/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptObject.cpp.o
[21/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaCallback.cpp.o
[22/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptTypedArray.cpp.o
[23/31] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptValue.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
/home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja 
-C 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/i615p4n6/arm64-v8a 
expo-modules-core
from /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android

Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6m 44s
466 actionable tasks: 466 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

how to solve this issue ?
